# Proper use of ToObservableChangeSet dynamic data reactiveui

Tags: dynamic, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I follow the example and create a reactiveui using dynamic data, I have no problem doing

```
List<TradingSy> myList = vmMwt.LoadList<TradingSy>();
        _myList.AddRange(myList);
        _myList.Connect()
           .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
           //.ObserveOnDispatcher()
           .Bind(_tradingSysCollection)
           .Subscribe();
```

I was hoping that when a user makes multiple changes or add or remove an item, I can easily find out what the changes are with ToObservableChangeSet when a user press Save button

OKCmd = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
            {

```
            _myList.Connect()
               //.ObserveOnDispatcher()
               .ToObservableChangeSet()
               .Bind(out _tradingChanges)
               .Subscribe();
```

but it is complaing that TradingChanges is invalid

private IObservableCollection _tradingChanges = new ObservableCollectionExtended();

Comment: Try having your field as the concrete class ObservableCollectionExtended rather than the interface

Comment: No it doesn't work. Please provide an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will resolve the issue:

```cs
private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IChangeSet<TradingSy>> _tradingChanges;
```

Comment: yes, it compiles, but then I still cannot access member of TradingSy.  I was hoping something like  _tradingChanges.ID, _tradingChanges.Name is available so I can save the changes to the database.